# JavaFX Line Chart Series Object Returning Null in Controller

Tags: java, javafx

I have a page system made with javafx, there is a main page that inherits a BorderPane (ApplicationWindow), and the secondary pages (super class Page.java) that are placed in the center of the main border pane inherit the AnchorPane class, there is a main method in the secondary pages called createView, which is called right in the constructor of these classes, it is responsible for placing the components of the page as children of the AnchorPane.

The secondary pages also have a helper class known as Controller. This Controller class is created in the constructor of the secondary pages and inherits ApplicationWindow so that it can later make references to the secondary pages.
So far, everything works normally, I can move between the pages and the controllers can do their job of updating the information and so on.

However, I'm having problems with charts.
In one of these classes I have a line graph, which is added to the scene by the createView method, I also add series to this chart, and get and set methods to reference these series by the controller. However, when I try to modify them from the controller, nothing happens, the chart doesn't update.

(Main class)

```
@Getter @Setter
public class MSPM extends Application {
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlMain = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/mspm/pages/AssetDetails.fxml"));

        applicationDirCreator();

        var root = new ApplicationWindow();
        var antialiasing = Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D)
                ? SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED
                : SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED;

        scene = new Scene(root, ApplicationWindow.MIN_WIDTH + 80, 768, false, antialiasing);

        Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(new PrimerLight().getUserAgentStylesheet());

        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/mspm/pages/DashboardCSS.css").toString());

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.setTitle("Brasens");

        Image brasensIcon = new Image(getClass().getResource("/mspm/resources/Icone File.png").toString());

        stage.getIcons().add(brasensIcon);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            Platform.exit();
            System.exit(0);
        });

        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "true");
        System.setProperty("prism.forceGPU", "true");
        launch(args);
    }

    public void applicationDirCreator() {
        File mainRoot = new File(Save.ApplicationFolder);
        if (!mainRoot.exists())
            mainRoot.mkdir();

        for (String dir : Save.ImportantDirectories) {
            File dirFile = new File(dir);
            if (!dirFile.exists())
                dirFile.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    public static void printNicerStackTrace(Exception e) {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = e.getStackTrace();

        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - " + e.getMessage());
        System.err.println("Stack trace:");

        for (StackTraceElement element : stackTraceElements) {
            System.err.printf("  at %s.%s (%s:%d)%n",
                    element.getClassName(),
                    element.getMethodName(),
                    element.getFileName(),
                    element.getLineNumber());
        }
    }

}
```

(Main page)

```
@Getter @Setter
public class ApplicationWindow  extends AnchorPane {

    public static final String BODY_ID = "body";
    public static final int MIN_WIDTH = 1280;
    MSPM mspm;

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();

    private NetworkManager networkManager;
    private ViewManager viewManager;

    public void init(){

    }

    public ApplicationWindow() {
        networkManager = new NetworkManager(new Token());
        viewManager = new ViewManager(this, networkManager);

        viewManager.setup(this);

        init();
        setPrefSize(1280, 800);
        getStyleClass().add("body");

        setId(BODY_ID);

        NodeUtils.setAnchors(this, Insets.EMPTY);

        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(borderPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(borderPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(borderPane, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(borderPane, 0.0);

        borderPane.getStyleClass().add("body");

        changePage(viewManager.getAssetDetailsView());
/* It calls the chart page and uses the changePage method to initialize the chart page and allow the Update method (Controller class) to perform its updates. */

        getChildren().addAll(borderPane);
    }

    public void realiseLogin(){
        borderPane.setLeft(getViewManager().getNavBar());
        borderPane.setTop(getViewManager().getTopMenu());

        changePage(viewManager.getDashboardView());
    }

    private Page currentPageLoaded;
    public void changePage(Page page){
        borderPane.setCenter(page);
        page.getController().init();

        if(currentPageLoaded != null)
            currentPageLoaded.getController().setUpdate(false);

        page.getController().setUpdate(true);

        currentPageLoaded = page;
    }
}
```

(ViewManager Object | This object stores the classes that reference the Page superclass. In other words, the View objects are stored here.
)

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ViewManager {
    private NavBar navBar;
    private TopMenu topMenu;

    private LoginView loginView;

    private DashboardView dashboardView;
    private NewAssetView newAssetView;
    private AssetsView assetsView;
    private NewWorkorderView newWorkorderView;
    private WorkordersView workordersView;

    private AssetDetailsView assetDetailsView;
    public ViewManager(ApplicationWindow applicationWindow, NetworkManager networkManager) {
        loginView = new LoginView(applicationWindow, networkManager);

        dashboardView = new DashboardView(applicationWindow, networkManager);
        newAssetView = new NewAssetView(applicationWindow, networkManager);
        assetsView = new AssetsView(applicationWindow, networkManager);
        newWorkorderView = new NewWorkorderView(applicationWindow, networkManager);
        workordersView = new WorkordersView(applicationWindow, networkManager);

        assetDetailsView = new AssetDetailsView(applicationWindow, networkManager);
    }

    public void setup(ApplicationWindow applicationWindow){
        navBar = new NavBar(applicationWindow);
        topMenu = new TopMenu(applicationWindow);
    }
}
```

(Secondary page)

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class Page extends AnchorPane {

    private ApplicationWindow applicationWindow;
    private NetworkManager networkManager;

    protected Controller controller;
    protected String CSS = getClass().getResource("/mspm/pages/DashboardCSS.css").toString();

    public Page(ApplicationWindow applicationWindow, NetworkManager networkManager, String CSS){
        this.applicationWindow = applicationWindow;
        this.networkManager = networkManager;
        this.CSS = getClass().getResource(CSS).toString();

        setPrefSize(1080, 725);
        getStyleClass().add("body");
        getStylesheets().add(this.CSS);

        createView();
    }
    public abstract void createView();
}
```

(Secondary page that refers to the chart)

```
@Getter @Setter
public class AssetDetailsView extends Page {
    private LineChart<String, Number> temperatureChart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());

    private XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

    public AssetDetailsView(ApplicationWindow applicationWindow, NetworkManager networkManager) {
        super(applicationWindow, networkManager, "/mspm/pages/DashboardCSS.css");
        this.controller = new AssetDetailsController(applicationWindow);
    }

    private Asset asset = new Asset();

    public AssetDetailsView() {
        this.controller = new AssetDetailsController(getApplicationWindow());
    }

    @Override
    public void createView() {
        getStyleClass().add("body");

        series = new XYChart.Series();

        temperatureChart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(temperatureChart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(temperatureChart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(temperatureChart, 0.0);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(temperatureChart, 0.0);

        series.setName("No of schools in an year");

        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+1970, 15));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+1980, 30));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+1990, 60));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+2000, 120));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+2013, 240));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+2014, 300));

    temperatureChart.getData().add(series);
    temperatureChart.setId("TEMP_CHART");

    System.out.println("Test 1: " + series);

    getChildren().add(temperatureChart);

    System.out.println("Test 2: " + series);
}

public void edit(){
    System.out.println("Edit: " + series);
}


}
```

(Controller of the secondary class that references the chart)

```
public class AssetDetailsController extends Controller {
    AssetDetailsView assetDetailsView;
    ApplicationWindow applicationWindow;
    public AssetDetailsController(ApplicationWindow applicationWindow) {
        this.applicationWindow = applicationWindow;
    }

    ArrayList<Data> assetData = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void init() {
        assetDetailsView = applicationWindow.getViewManager().getAssetDetailsView();
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        if(isUpdatable()) {
            assetDetailsView.getSeries().getData().clear();

            assetDetailsView.getSeries().setName("No of schools in an year");

            Random gerador = new Random();

            assetDetailsView.getSeries().getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+1970, 15 * gerador.nextInt()));
            assetDetailsView.getSeries().getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+1980, 30 * gerador.nextInt()));
            assetDetailsView.getSeries().getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+1990, 60 * gerador.nextInt()));
            assetDetailsView.getSeries().getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+2000, 120 * gerador.nextInt()));
            assetDetailsView.getSeries().getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+2013, 240 * gerador.nextInt()));
            assetDetailsView.getSeries().getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+2014, 300 * gerador.nextInt()));

            assetDetailsView.edit();
        }
    }

}
```

(Super class controller)

```
@Getter @Setter
public abstract class Controller {

    protected boolean releasedUpdate = false;

    public int delay = 100;

    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public Controller() {
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            Platform.runLater(this::update);
        }, 0, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public abstract void init();

    public abstract void update();

    public void setUpdate(boolean releasedUpdate) {
        this.releasedUpdate = releasedUpdate;
    }
    public Boolean isUpdatable() {
        return releasedUpdate;
    }

}
```

When I do a System.out.print on my Series variable it returns Series[null], even in methods that are in the AssetDetailsView class and are called after createView this happens.

My goal is to update the charts on the pages using the Update method of the controller class, doing this from within the Thread and Platform.runLater.

**-TEST-**

By null I mean the following.
I've put some screenshots to test the Series in the AssetDetailsView class, one of these screenshots is in a method that is called by the AssetDetailsController (edit() method).

The result in the console was as follows:

```
Test 1: Series[No of schools in an year ]
Test 2: Series[No of schools in an year ]
Edit: Series[null]
```

For the AssetDetailsView class:

```
@Override
public void createView() {
    series.setName("No of schools in an year ");
    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(""+1970, 15));


    temperatureChart.getData().add(series);
    temperatureChart.setId("TEMP_CHART");

    System.out.println("Test 1: " + series);

    getChildren().add(temperatureChart);

    System.out.println("Test 2: " + series);
}

public void edit(){
    System.out.println("Edit: " + series);
}
```

I've done something similar in previous projects, but in those I used FXML, while in this project I'm creating the page directly with the components. I don't know if this influences anything, perhaps the fact that I don't have ID references?

Comment: Create and post a [mre]. There is too much code here, and as far as I can tell it won't even compile (your `AssetDetailsView` has a no-arg constructor which implicitly calls the superclass no-arg constructor, which doesn't exist). Additionally, please clarify exactly what the issue is. What is `null`? Do you get a `NullPointerException` (if so, post the complete stack trace)?

Comment: Off-topic: consider using an `Animation` (e.g. a `Timeline`) to schedule calls on the FX Application Thread at fixed intervals. This will avoid unnecessarily creating new threads.

Comment: From the edit to the post, it is clear that you are calling `edit()` on a different instance to the one on which `createView()` was called. (In the instance on which `edit()` is called, `series.setName(...)` has not been called.) This suggests you are probably updating a different `LineChart` that is not part of the scene graph. There's not enough information in the question to know why that is happening.

Comment: @James_D
The createView method is called in the constructor of the Page class, i.e. createView is executed at the beginning of the ApplicationWindow.
There is a helper object there called ViewManager, which creates the View classes and at that point createView is executed and waits until it is added to the BorderPane.
I don't know if this would be the best way to make these transitions between pages, do you think there is a more efficient way?

Comment: The structure of all of this is a bit of a code smell. I don't recommend subclassing `AnchorPane` all over the place here. From a design perspective, you should inheritance to add new functionality to classes, not to configure instances of those classes. From a UI perspective you end up with a bunch of `AnchorPane`s with only one child node, which just makes the `AnchorPane` redundant. Use some kind of creational pattern (factory) instead. (Your `ViewManager` class already acts as some kind of factory.)

Comment: Only one of the constructors for `AssetDetailsView` calls `createView()`, as far as I can tell (a lot of what is happening is obscured by the Lombok library, which in my opinion is unmitigated garbage). I also don't see where `init()` is called, though it must be being called somewhere else you'd end up with null pointer exceptions all over the place.

Comment: @James_D It's interesting because I can update anything on the page from the controller class, except the charts.

Comment: Ok, after some tests and modifications I managed to inject the series into the chart correctly via the controller class, however the chart doesn't update and doesn't show the series.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re expecting anyone to say that hasn’t already been said. You clearly somehow have two instances of `AssetDetailsView`. Unless you create and post a [mre] it is not possible to know why.

Comment: @James_D I've created a project with the components in question and posted it on github:  https://github.com/MatheusMarkies/ReproducibleExample.git

Comment: You should post the mre in the question, not as an external link. The problem is in your inheritance hierarchy, which is fundamentally broken. (It is not safe to call overridable methods from a constructor.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from your inheritance hierarchy, which is fundamentally broken. It is not safe to call an overridable method from a constructor. See [Is there any way to initialize member variables of a subclass in Java before the superclass' constructor is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529612/is-there-any-way-to-initialize-member-variables-of-a-subclass-in-java-before-the) for more details. This is an item in Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java* (which every serious Java programmer needs to read and be familiar with).

In your `Page` class you have:

```
public abstract class Page extends AnchorPane {

    private ApplicationWindow applicationWindow;
    private NetworkManager networkManager;

    protected Controller controller;
    protected String CSS = getClass().getResource("/mspm/pages/DashboardCSS.css").toString();

    public Page(ApplicationWindow applicationWindow, NetworkManager networkManager, String CSS){

        // ...

        createView();
    }
    public abstract void createView();
}
```

where the constructor calls the overridable method `createView()`.

In the subclass `AssetDetailsView` you do the following:

```
public class AssetDetailsView extends Page {
    private LineChart<String, Number> temperatureChart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());

    private XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();

    public AssetDetailsView(ApplicationWindow applicationWindow, NetworkManager networkManager) {
        super(applicationWindow, networkManager, "/mspm/pages/DashboardCSS.css");
        this.controller = new AssetDetailsController(applicationWindow);
    }



    @Override
    public void createView() {

        // ...

        series = new XYChart.Series();

        // ...
        temperatureChart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());

        // ...

        series.setName("No of schools in an year");

        // ...

        temperatureChart.getData().add(series);
    }

    public void edit(){
        System.out.println("Edit: " + series);
    }


}
```

If we rewrite this in equivalent form, with the inline initialization being performed in the constructor, the issue is clearer:

```
public class AssetDetailsView extends Page {
    private LineChart<String, Number> temperatureChart ;

    private XYChart.Series<String, Number> ;

    public AssetDetailsView(ApplicationWindow applicationWindow, NetworkManager networkManager) {
        super(applicationWindow, networkManager, "/mspm/pages/DashboardCSS.css");
        this.temperatureChart = new new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        this.series = new Series<>();
        this.controller = new AssetDetailsController(applicationWindow);
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void createView() {

        // ...

        series = new XYChart.Series();

        // ...
        temperatureChart = new LineChart<>(new CategoryAxis(), new NumberAxis());

        // ...

        series.setName("No of schools in an year");

        // ...

        temperatureChart.getData().add(series);
    }

    public void edit(){
        System.out.println("Edit: " + series);
    }


}
```

The superclass constructor is invoked first, by necessity. That constructor calls `createView()`, which sets the values of `temperatureChart` and `series`, and sets those objects as child nodes of the object. The remainder of the subclass initialization then continues, which redefines the values of `temperatureChart` and `series` to be references to new objects (not the ones added to the scene graph). Subsequent calls to `getSeries()`, for example, return the new series (not the one used in the chart that is actually displayed, or has its name set).

Here is a simplified version of the same structure. The superclass invokes an abstract, overridable method `initializeX()` whose purpose is to initialize the variable `x` returned by the `getX()` method.

The subclass overrides `initializeX()` to initialize `x` to its "correct" value of 54. However, the inline intialization completes later, setting `x` to the incorrect value of 42.

```
public abstract class Super {
    public Super() {
        initializeX();
    }

    public abstract void initializeX() ;
    public abstract int getX();

    public static class Sub extends Super {
        private int x = 42 ;

        @Override
        public void initializeX() {
            x = 6 * 9 ;
        }

        @Override
        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Super sub = new Sub();
        System.out.println("What do you get if you multiple 6 by 9? "+sub.getX());
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is not the answer you want to hear, but here goes:

The real issue here is that your application is over-engineered. In particular, it relies far too much on inheritance. I recommend reading *Effective Java* and redesigning this in a more robust way. There is no need to subclass `AnchorPane` simply for the purpose of defining reusable functionality. There is no need to use inheritance to control creation of objects; use some kind of creational pattern (abstract factory, for example) instead.

If you need an immediate hack, simply removing the inline initialization of `temperatureChart` and `series` might fix the immediate issue; however the design problems will inevitably lead to more issues arising at a later stage. In my opinion, it will be better to start over now than invest more on a broken design and have to do more rewriting later.